# Loop to calculate weights and create new variables

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, iteration

If I start with the following data set and call `df`:

```
   A    B
  0.8   0.9
  0.99  0.88
  0.7   0.9658
  0.65  0.6684
```

And my aim is to achieve the data set below which has a set of new variables using different weights from my initial set:

```
    A        B      A_10    A_20    A_30    A_40    A_50
    0.8     0.9     0.89    0.88    0.87    0.86    0.85
    0.99    0.88    0.891   0.902   0.913   0.924   0.935
    0.7     0.9658  0.93922 0.91264 0.88606 0.85948 0.8329
    0.65    0.6684  0.66656 0.66472 0.66288 0.66104 0.6592
```

The code I used is:

```
   for (i in 10:90) {
        df <- df %>% mutate(A_[i] =(A*[i]/100)+(B*((1-[i])/100))) }
```

I got the following error:

> Error: unexpected '=' in:"  df <- df %>% mutate(A_[i] ="*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R alternative way:

```
df[paste0('A_', seq(10, 90, 10))] <- 
    lapply(seq(10, 90, 10), function(i) (df$A * i + df$B * (100 - i)) / 100)
# > df
#      A      B    A_10    A_20    A_30    A_40   A_50    A_60    A_70    A_80    A_90
# 1 0.80 0.9000 0.89000 0.88000 0.87000 0.86000 0.8500 0.84000 0.83000 0.82000 0.81000
# 2 0.99 0.8800 0.89100 0.90200 0.91300 0.92400 0.9350 0.94600 0.95700 0.96800 0.97900
# 3 0.70 0.9658 0.93922 0.91264 0.88606 0.85948 0.8329 0.80632 0.77974 0.75316 0.72658
# 4 0.65 0.6684 0.66656 0.66472 0.66288 0.66104 0.6592 0.65736 0.65552 0.65368 0.65184
```

Comment: @this one worked like a glove perfect! thanks very much to all R community

Answer (score 3):

The main thing is that to give dynamic naming of `dplyr` you should use the syntax  `%>% mutate(!!paste0("BG_", i) := A + B)`.

```
for (i in seq(10, 90, 10)) {

  df <- df %>% 
    mutate(!!paste0("BG_", i) := (A*i/100)+(B*((1-i)/100))) 
}

df
#    A      B     BG_10     BG_20     BG_30     BG_40     BG_50     BG_60
# 1 0.80 0.9000 -0.001000 -0.011000 -0.021000 -0.031000 -0.041000 -0.051000
# 2 0.99 0.8800  0.019800  0.030800  0.041800  0.052800  0.063800  0.074800
# 3 0.70 0.9658 -0.016922 -0.043502 -0.070082 -0.096662 -0.123242 -0.149822
# 4 0.65 0.6684  0.004844  0.003004  0.001164 -0.000676 -0.002516 -0.004356
#     BG_70     BG_80     BG_90
# 1 -0.061000 -0.071000 -0.081000
# 2  0.085800  0.096800  0.107800
# 3 -0.176402 -0.202982 -0.229562
# 4 -0.006196 -0.008036 -0.009876
```

Data used:

```
df <- read.table(text = "A    B
0.8   0.9
0.99  0.88
0.7   0.9658
0.65  0.6684", head=T)
```

Comment: It should be seq(10, 90, 10).

Comment: hi and tks again did implement this way byt then it only created the variable BG_90.... please see code below ::::for (i in seq(from=10, to=90, by=10)) {
  df2 <- df %>% 
    mutate(!!paste0("BG_", i) := (BG_total*i)+(onet_total*((100-1)/100))) 
}

Comment: @ Suren  , Hi , if I do for (i in 10:90) I get 85 variables if I do for(I in seq(10,90,10) I only get 5 variables . To be specific I only get the last iteration BG_90.

Answer (score 0):

We could also parse this as an expression

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
s1 <- seq(10, 90, 10)
# or could be
#s1 <- 10:90
expr1 <- paste(glue::glue("(A * {s1} + B * (100 - {s1}))/100"), collapse=";")
nm1 <- paste0("A_", s1)   
out <- df %>%
        mutate(!!! parse_exprs(expr1)) %>%
        rename_at(vars(-one_of(names(df))), ~ nm1)

out
#     A      B    A_10    A_20    A_30    A_40   A_50    A_60    A_70    A_80    A_90
#1 0.80 0.9000 0.89000 0.88000 0.87000 0.86000 0.8500 0.84000 0.83000 0.82000 0.81000
#2 0.99 0.8800 0.89100 0.90200 0.91300 0.92400 0.9350 0.94600 0.95700 0.96800 0.97900
#3 0.70 0.9658 0.93922 0.91264 0.88606 0.85948 0.8329 0.80632 0.77974 0.75316 0.72658
#4 0.65 0.6684 0.66656 0.66472 0.66288 0.66104 0.6592 0.65736 0.65552 0.65368 0.65184
```